# Capitalizing individual characters in string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have to capitalize the first and last name in my string array, but I'm stuck on how to access the specific value after I input my string value into an array.

Here are my two functions, the first one reads the values into two separate arrays, and the second is supposed to capitalize the first and last names while changing all other characters to lower case.

```
void read(string names[],int DVDrent[],int& n)
{
   n=0;          // # of data calculated
   cin >> names[n] >> DVDrent[n]
   while(cin)
     {
       n++;
       cin >> names[n] >> DVDrent[n];
     }
}

void reformat(string& names)
{
    int nlen;
    nlen = names.length();
    names[0] = toupper(names[0]);
    for (int i=1; i<nlen; i++)
       {
           if (names[i] == ',')
           names[i+1] = toupper(names[i+1]);
           names[i+2] = tolower(names[i+2]);
       }
}
```

My second function works if I do simply store my data as a string. I'm stuck right now because I'm not sure how to read the specific characters of my array.

For reference, the data that I enter is as follows.

```
./a.out < data > output
```

Data:

```
smith,EMILY 3   
Johnson,Daniel 2   
williAMS,HanNAH 0   
joneS,Jacob 4   
bROwn,MicHAEL 5   
DAVIS,ETHAn 2   
millER,soPhiA 0   
TAYlor,matthew 1   
andERSON,aNNa 7
```

Desired output:

```
Smith,Emily 3    
Johnson,Daniel 2   
William,Hannah 0   
.   
.   
.   
Anderson,Anna 7   
etc.
```

Comment: Can you post your `main()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your `reformat()` method:

```
void reformat(string& names) {

    bool isUpper = true; // store if the next letter should be upper

    for(size_t i = 0; i < names.length(); ++i) {

        if (names[i] == ',') {
            isUpper = true; // if it's a comma, make the next letter upper
        }
        else if (isUpper) {
            names[i] = toupper(names[i]);
            isUpper = false; // make the next letter lower
        }
        else {
            names[i] = tolower(names[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the compiler error I get after using your reformat method. I'm still experiencing the same error.  

invalid initialization of non-const reference of type std::string from a temporary of type std::string

Comment: If I had to guess, it's probably because you haven't initialized `string[]` before you pass it to your `read()` function.